# How to print a dictionary using string format in python

Tags: python

When I try to run the following code

```
a= """{"hi":"hello "} {user}"""
a.format({"user":"xxx"})
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"hi"'
```

Please let me know how to solve this problem, I have been trying for a long time.

Comment: You are not passing a value for `hi`? What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: how about removing the " " from the "hi"

Comment: I cannot make any sense of your code. What do you want to achieve? From string to dictionary?

Comment: still don't understand what you want, what is a?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `{` and `}` and then you need to pass keyword arguments to `format`, not a dict

```
a= """{{"hi":"hello "}} {user}"""
print a.format(**{"user":"xxx"})
print a.format(user="xxx")
```

output

```
{"hi":"hello "} xxx
{"hi":"hello "} xxx
```

Or if you are trying to get the string representation:

```
a= """{{"hi":"hello "}} {user}"""
print a.format(user=str({"user":"xxx"}))
```

output

```
{"hi":"hello "} {'user': 'xxx'}
```

Comment: what if a= """{"hi":{"hello ":"how"}} {user}""" and I need to print {"hi":{"hello":"how"}} xxx

Comment: You need to escape all of them, you would need to double all of the ones that aren't used for formatting. `"""{{"hi":{{"hello ":"how"}}}} {user}"""`